# How to structure an app using Web Components

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'd love to do more with Web Components, but I am uncertain about how to use them the right way. I am used to building web apps in React, Vue.js etc.

So in React people try to abstract everything in a component to make it more reusable and manageable, like `<Input />`, `<Button />`, `<Header />`. I wonder if this approach should be used for Web Components as well?

Or is it better to do it like GitHub does, looking at their dropdown menus as an example which are nicely wrapped as a component? But they don't use them everywhere, rather for specific situations.

Is there a recommendation? Any best-practices on how to structure an app and its pieces with Web Components?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple!
It all depends on you.
You need to see how many components have been reused in the project you are developing?
This may be different for each project.
Component development is certainly faster, easier, and easier to develop.
Typically in applications that are designed with a specific template design, the reuse rate of components is high, but not in creative designs.
Ultimately it's up to you to decide